# Oracle SQL : how to specify Time Zone Region

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, zone

```
to_date('30/03/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Underlined, as hours are not specified, that means that hour is '00:00'
I would like to specify that this is for Europe/Paris time zone region.
Can you help me set-up this ?
Thanks

Comment: Dates don't hold time zone information; you would need a `timestamp with time zone` value. What are you doing with this value - inserting it into a table? If so what data type if the column? And is the string part being supplied, or is it a fixed value - so you could use a timestamp literal, e.g. `timestamp '2022-03-30 00:00:00 Europe/Paris'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DATE` data type has the components: year, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those components and **NEVER** stores anything else (such as a time zone); so it is impossible to store a time zone in a `DATE` data type.

A `TIMESTAMP` data type has the components: year, month, day, hour, minute and second and, optionally, can store fractional seconds.

A `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type has the components: year, month, day, hour, minute, second and time zone and, optionally, can store fractional seconds information.

Therefore, if you want to store a time zone then you should use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and not `DATE`.

Your code would then be:

```sql
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('30/03/2022 Europe/Paris', 'DD/MM/YYYY TZR')
```

or using a timestamp literal:

```sql
TIMESTAMP '2022-03-30 00:00:00 Europe/Paris'
```

or, if you want to pass in your date in that format and add the time zone in a two-step process:

```sql
FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('30/03/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Europe/Paris')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b74783991b85fa3138c7f472c85f431)*